# Help me finding dependency list

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have two table employee table and employee dependency table.
Employee tooks like below.

```
insert into E values(1,'Adam')
insert into E values(2,'Bob')
insert into E values(3,'Candy')
insert into E values(4,'Doug')
insert into E values(5,'Earl')
insert into E values(6,'Fran')
```

Employee dependency table looks like below

```
insert into Ed values(3,'2')
insert into Ed values(3,'5')
insert into Ed values(2,'1')
insert into Ed values(2,'4')
insert into Ed values(5,'6')
```

I need to find the dependency list like below

```
Eid  Ename     Dname
3     Candy    Bob,Fran
```

Please help me finding the above.

Comment: I tride doing it.But i really dont know where wil i get that opetion.That would be great if u let me knw.PLZ

Comment: Candy should be Bob and Earl, right?

Comment: @oliholz,@tomkpunkt:Thanks oliholz. I came to know the inportence of accenpting the answer

Comment: @Alex: Yes Alex. Thanks for the resolving my issue.

Comment: @ALL : Is there any other way other then making use of MXL Path in Stuff function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup:

```
create table E(id int , name varchar(100))

insert into E values(1,'Adam')
insert into E values(2,'Bob')
insert into E values(3,'Candy')
insert into E values(4,'Doug')
insert into E values(5,'Earl')
insert into E values(6,'Fran')

create table Ed(id1 int, id2 int)

insert into Ed values(3,2) 
insert into Ed values(3,5)
insert into Ed values(2,1)
insert into Ed values(2,4)
insert into Ed values(5,6)
```

Query:

```
select Name,
    stuff((select ',' + e1.name
    from Ed
        join E e1 on
            Ed.id2 = e1.id
    where Ed.id1 = E.id
    for xml path('')), 1, 1, '') as Dependents
from E
```

Result:

```
Name       Dependents
---------- --------------
Adam       NULL
Bob        Adam,Doug
Candy      Bob,Earl
Doug       NULL
Earl       Fran
Fran       NULL
```

If you need to show only those that have dependents:

```
select *
from
(
    select Name,
        stuff((select ',' + e1.name
        from Ed
            join E e1 on
                Ed.id2 = e1.id
        where Ed.id1 = E.id
        for xml path('')), 1, 1, '') as Dependents
    from E
) tt
where Dependents is not null
```

Comment: Hello : I am able to get the output.
But i am unable to understand the logic u made.Could you please explain me.

Comment: `for xml` is one of the ways to make coma separated list. `stuff` is just to remove leading coma. Example here: http://blog.cromwellhaus.com/2009/03/stuff-amp-for-xml-path/

Comment: Is there any other way other then making use of MXL Path in Stuff function?

Comment: `FOR XML PATH` the way to make XML http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189885.aspx. `FOR XML` is the easiest way to do this.

Comment: @Alex aza: U r right. I will do that. thanks alot for u r time. It was really helpfull for me.